# How to bind objectdatasource with a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

UPDATE: THIS IS THE WORKING VERSION.

```
public DataSet GetObjects()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var source = from p in CommentsList
                 select new { p.Img, p.Name, p.Comment };
    dt.Columns.Add("Img");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Comment");

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        DataRow userDetailsRow=dt.NewRow();
        userDetailsRow["Img"] = item.Img;
        userDetailsRow["Name"] = item.Name;

        DataRow comments = dt.NewRow();
        userDetailsRow["Comment"] = item.Comment;
        dt.Rows.Add(userDetailsRow);
        //dt.Rows.Add(comments);
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    return ds;
}
```

My GridView columns section looks like this:

```
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="500px" />
                     <ItemStyle Width="500px" Height="100px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                      <ItemStyle Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgName" runat="server"  imageUrl='<%# Bind("Img") %>'></asp:Image><br />
                        <asp:Hyperlink ID="hyperLink" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' ></asp:Hyperlink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

UPDATE: The problem that I have got now is with the size of rows..that are huge and dont update  with the content within,,,example: Header 33%, Row 33%, footer 33%..even though the content of the header is 10% of the gridview..how do i fix that?

Comment: Is this line in your ObjectDataSource method correct `userDetailsRow["User"] = item.Img;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Column in your DataTable with the name of `Img` before using this in DataBinding

```
userDetailsRow["User"] = item.Img;
```

should be

```
userDetailsRow["img"] = item.Img;
```

Comment: But then it would fail because he did not add the `"img"` column. :)

Comment: lol..i finally got it to work..but with one field the table row height is huge..is there a way for the grid height and row height be proportionate to the content in it?

Comment: You can check with GridView Css properties.

Comment: See the update above..  do you mean i need to create a css file by myself.. I try to play with the height of the header ..setting it 30px but it keeps setting the whole thing proportionally

Comment: There are gridview style available for that you can check.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `Img` property. Plain and simple. This is why you have problems accessing it: it does not exist.You should create the property *AND* populate it.

**Update**

You should do this:

```
var source = from p in CommentsList
             select new { p.Img, p.Name, p.Comment };
dt.Columns.Add("User");
dt.Columns.Add("Comment");
dt.Columns.Add("Img");
```

and then this:

```
DataRow userDetailsRow=dt.NewRow();
    userDetailsRow["Img"] = item.Img;
    userDetailsRow["User"] = item.Name;
```

Fix where it applies.

Comment: Thanks Adrian..i solved the issue..see the code updated above